# Resolving a deferred Q multiple times

Tags: node.js, q, deferred

As I know deferred can be resolved only once and also nodejs caches the required module at the first step in order to prevent loading it every single time, but what I want to do is renewing deferred Q object each time I want to resolve/reject a returned value.
This is my server code :

```
// server.js

app.get('/api/posts', function(req,res,next){
    var insta = require('./upRunner'); // this's the main obstacle 
    insta.returner().then(function(data){
    // .... 
    };
});
```

and the code for ./upRunner.js is :

```
 // upRunner.js
 ...
 var defer = Q.defer();
 upRunner();

    function extractor(body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body), scripts= [];
    $('script').each(function(i, elem){ 
        scripts[i] = $(this).text();
    }); 
    var str = scripts[6],
    newData = JSON.parse(str.substring(str.indexOf("{"), str.lastIndexOf(";"))).entry_data.TagPage[0].tag.media.page_info;
    grabber(str);
    return newData;
 }
 function grabber(str) {
 newData = JSON.parse(str.substring(str.indexOf("{"), str.lastIndexOf(";"))).entry_data.TagPage[0].tag.top_posts.nodes;
 newData.sort(dynamicSort('-date'));
 newData.forEach(function(elem,index,array){
    if (instaImages.length >= 10) {
        defer.resolve(instaImages);
    } else {            
        instaImages.push(elem);
    }
});
}

function upRunner(newData){

profilePage = !(tagPage = URL.includes("/tags/") ? true : false);
if (!newData) {
    request(URL,{jar:true}, function(err, resp, body){
    var $ = cheerio.load(body), scripts= [];
    $('script').each(function(i, elem){ 
        scripts[i] = $(this).text();
    }); 
    var str = scripts[6],
    newData = JSON.parse(str.substring(str.indexOf("{"), str.lastIndexOf(";"))).entry_data.TagPage[0].tag.media.page_info;
    upRunner(newData);
});
} else { 
    if (newData.has_next_page) {
        requester(URL, newData.end_cursor).then(function(body){
            newData = extractor(body);
            upRunner(newData);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('it\'s finished\n');
    }

 function returner() {
     return deferred.promise;
 }
 exports.returner = returner;
```

As you see I'm almost renewing upRunner returner deferred promise each time server get /api/posts address, but the problem is the deferred object still return the old resolved value.

There is the grabber function which resolve value, so defer can not be localized in a single function.

Comment: We can't really help you without understanding more about where the deferred is created and when.  In a nutshell, you need to expose a method from your module that creates a new deferred each time you want to use a new async operation.  I know you've commented that you can't just make a new deferred in your `returner()` method, but if that's really the case, then you need to show us why and where the deferred can be created.  If you want a new async operation to be promise-based each time you call it, you have to create a new deferred/promise.  Period.  It's up to you to figure out where.

Comment: @jfriend00 i edited the code, i think the problem can be solved by changing the structure of my code and functionality of methods , does it make sense for you now that where i should use the promise ?

Comment: `requester().then()` informs us that `requester()` returns a promise, but how about `request()`, As written it accepts a callback but does it also return a promise?

Answer (score 2):

Try to initialized `deferred` value locally to get new resolve value.

```
 function returner() {
     var defer= $q.defer();
     return deferred.promise;
 };

 exports.returner = returner;
```

Comment: there's another function which use defer in order to resolve the value, so it can't be initialized locally.